# Using spatial pyramid representation with SIFT descriptor

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to use the SIFT descriptor with spatial pyramid representation and SVM but unfortunately I still have some missing point in how to follow the steps in applying SPR and make the final representation of the features of each image.

So I would appreciate any kind of help that allowing me to understand this algorithm very well.

Comment: Which missing points in following the steps in applying SPR do you have? Which algorithm do you mean exactly, what are the problems exactly. As it is it's difficult to understand what is going on.

Comment: The missing points listed as below:
1- At the beginning the image is blurred with Gaussian Filter or not because some papers said that each level of the pyramid is blurred with different scale and didnt notice that?

2- when we divide the image into block of fixed size. How we constrcut the histogram and how we combine the histogram of all the sub-blocks and generate the final one.

3- In the matching or classification process, each level of the pyramid give its own accuracy ? or all the levels histogram are aggregate again to construct the final feature vector of the image?

Comment: Could you put the points in your comment also into the question? They will surely improve the question a lot. :) Also please specify what you mean by "some papers" (which ones?) "didn't notice that" (who and what exactly)

Comment: If you are expert in the area, can you please give the steps in implementing the spatial pyramid representation with SIFT descriptor.